# Why won't my Minecraft loot table drop more than 64 blocks/items? 1.19.4

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I've been working on a data pack for me and my friends that has a mob called a "loot pig" that is supposed to drop a lot of rare and valuable loot upon death, and I used the loot table generator to help me in accomplishing my goal. The problem is that I want this pig to drop "stacks" worth of goods without the use of the looting enchant (still using it but the result I want is if you kill it WITHOUT looting it will still drop more than a stack), but it won't drop more than 64 of any given item.

I've tried to fix this by adding multiple of the same "set_count" to the loot table, but that doesn't seem to work. I've tried to look it up but so far either no one else has this issue or I'm missing something obvious. Can someone help me?

Heres is the code:

```
  "type": "minecraft:entity",
  "pools": [
    {
      "rolls": 1,
      "entries": [
        {
          "type": "minecraft:item",
          "weight": 10,
          "name": "minecraft:diamond_ore",
          "functions": [
            {
              "function": "minecraft:set_count",
              "count": {
                "type": "minecraft:uniform",
                "min": 64,
                "max": 256
              }
            },
            {
              "function": "minecraft:looting_enchant",
              "count": {
                "type": "minecraft:uniform",
                "min": 0,
                "max": 128
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "minecraft:item",
          "weight": 10,
          "name": "minecraft:copper_ore",
          "functions": [
            {
              "function": "minecraft:set_count",
              "count": {
                "type": "minecraft:uniform",
                "min": 512,
                "max": 1024
              }
            },
            {
              "function": "minecraft:furnace_smelt",
              "conditions": [
                {
                  "condition": "minecraft:entity_properties",
                  "entity": "this",
                  "predicate": {
                    "flags": {
                      "is_on_fire": true
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "function": "minecraft:looting_enchant",
              "count": {
                "type": "minecraft:uniform",
                "min": 0,
                "max": 1024
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "minecraft:item",
          "weight": 10,
          "name": "minecraft:iron_ore",
          "functions": [
            {
              "function": "minecraft:set_count",
              "count": {
                "min": 128,
                "max": 256
              }
            },
            {
              "function": "minecraft:furnace_smelt",
              "conditions": [
                {
                  "condition": "minecraft:entity_properties",
                  "entity": "this",
                  "predicate": {
                    "flags": {
                      "is_on_fire": true
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "function": "minecraft:looting_enchant",
              "count": {
                "type": "minecraft:uniform",
                "min": 0,
                "max": 256
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "minecraft:item",
          "weight": 10,
          "name": "minecraft:gold_ore",
          "functions": [
            {
              "function": "minecraft:set_count",
              "count": {
                "min": 128,
                "max": 256
              }
            },
            {
              "function": "minecraft:furnace_smelt",
              "conditions": [
                {
                  "condition": "minecraft:entity_properties",
                  "entity": "this",
                  "predicate": {
                    "flags": {
                      "is_on_fire": true
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "function": "minecraft:looting_enchant",
              "count": {
                "type": "minecraft:uniform",
                "min": 0,
                "max": 256
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "minecraft:item",
          "weight": 10,
          "name": "minecraft:emerald_ore",
          "functions": [
            {
              "function": "minecraft:set_count",
              "count": {
                "type": "minecraft:uniform",
                "min": 128,
                "max": 384
              },
              "add": false
            },
            {
              "function": "minecraft:looting_enchant",
              "count": {
                "type": "minecraft:uniform",
                "min": 0,
                "max": 256
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "minecraft:item",
          "weight": 10,
          "name": "minecraft:ancient_debris",
          "functions": [
            {
              "function": "minecraft:set_count",
              "count": {
                "type": "minecraft:uniform",
                "min": 128,
                "max": 512
              }
            },
            {
              "function": "minecraft:furnace_smelt",
              "conditions": [
                {
                  "condition": "minecraft:entity_properties",
                  "entity": "this",
                  "predicate": {
                    "flags": {
                      "is_on_fire": true
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "function": "minecraft:looting_enchant",
              "count": {
                "type": "minecraft:uniform",
                "min": 0,
                "max": 384
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "minecraft:item",
          "weight": 10,
          "name": "minecraft:nether_star",
          "functions": [
            {
              "function": "minecraft:set_count",
              "count": 32
            },
            {
              "function": "minecraft:looting_enchant",
              "count": {
                "type": "minecraft:uniform",
                "min": 0,
                "max": 32
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "minecraft:item",
          "weight": 10,
          "name": "minecraft:lapis_lazuli",
          "functions": [
            {
              "function": "minecraft:set_count",
              "count": {
                "type": "minecraft:uniform",
                "min": 128,
                "max": 384
              }
            },
            {
              "function": "minecraft:looting_enchant",
              "count": 256
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "minecraft:item",
          "weight": 10,
          "name": "minecraft:golden_carrot",
          "functions": [
            {
              "function": "minecraft:set_count",
              "count": {
                "type": "minecraft:uniform",
                "min": 512,
                "max": 1024
              }
            },
            {
              "function": "minecraft:looting_enchant",
              "count": {
                "type": "minecraft:uniform",
                "min": 0,
                "max": 512
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "minecraft:item",
          "weight": 10,
          "name": "minecraft:gunpowder",
          "functions": [
            {
              "function": "minecraft:set_count",
              "count": {
                "type": "minecraft:uniform",
                "min": 512,
                "max": 2048
              }
            },
            {
              "function": "minecraft:looting_enchant",
              "count": {
                "type": "minecraft:uniform",
                "min": 0,
                "max": 512
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: If I had to guess, there's probably a limit of 64 items per loot table entry. You could add multiple pools, but that might not accomplish what you're trying to do.